# Wordpress - wp_enqueue_script / wp_enqueue_style doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I have coded myself a little WP-Plugin, where I do

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');        
wp_enqueue_script('myapp1', $pluginpath . 'build/js/app.min.js', array('jquery')); 
wp_enqueue_style("myapp2", $pluginpath . 'build/css/style.css');
```

while testing on my localhost, everythink worked fine, so I uploaded everything to my server and there, my plugin works, too, but the `app.min.js` and the `style.css` is not included(?)

what could be the cause for this?

Comment: Which action are you using to run these enqueue functions?

Comment: I do a `add_shortcode('myform', 'add_form');` .. in `function add_form()` I do enqueue the CSS/JS

Comment: That's too late. By the time the shortcode is run `wp_head()` output (where it needs to be printed) has already run.

Comment: @Gerald Schneider.. but how does it work on my localhost then? oO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files that are referenced with `wp_enqueue_script()`/`wp_enqueue_style()` are used in the `wp_head()` function.

By the time your shortcode is evaluated this part is already finished, so your files will never be referenced.

You have to add your style using the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action:

```
function my_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style("myapp2", $pluginpath . 'build/css/style.css');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

There is no way around that, because the style belongs in the head.

For your JS though, you can use another parameter to load it in the footer:

```
wp_enqueue_script('myapp1', $pluginpath . 'build/js/app.min.js', array('jquery'), "1.0", true);
```

You can add this in your shortcode so at least the JS will only be loaded when it is needed.

(The version number can be anything you want, it is useful to increment it when you release new version of your JS file, so browsers don't use old versions from cache.)

Comment: dude !! that was it!! :) thank you so much! .. I have struggling with this for two days now :)

Answer (score 0):

Well first thing that comes to my mind is that the **$pluginpath** variable is set incorrectly. Check the browser console if the files gets enqueued at all and if they do they should produce 404 errors. If the error is produced then you can see the file path and check if it is correct (which should not be if it seems that files are missing).

Also, you don't have to enqueue jQuery because WordPress core does that.

Comment: WordPress does not enqueue jquery by default. If no theme or plugin enqueues it it is not loaded.

Comment: Okay, my bad. Guess I have always had some plugin which has loaded jquery.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I checked it all and there is absolutely no Plugin-CSS/JS enqueued.  I have also output the `$pluginpath` which gives me a absolute path to the CSS-File (I can call it in the browser, that works).